# OpenAPI oneOf displaying items twice (problem)?

Tags: jsonschema, openapi

having a head-scratching problem.

my OneOf array "items" are duplicated in the API docs, like this:

[image]

My guess is that the problem is located in the class prop in entity model or in the api file.

models/entity.json

```
{
  "$id": "entity.json",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["id", "countryCode", "class"],
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "readOnly": true,
      "allOf": [{
        "$ref": "./uuid.json"
      }],
      "description": "UUID of entity",
      "example": "49ad7378-121c-4a53-9894-dfd14a7b4877"
    },
    "countryCode": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Country code",
      "example": "SE",
      "pattern": "[A-Z][A-Z]"
    },
    "class": {
      "description": "Entity classification",
      "oneOf":[
        {
          "$ref": "./person.json"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "./sme.json"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "./corp.json"
        }
      ]
    },
```

schema/entity/api.json

```
"post": {
        "summary": "Create an entitiy",
        "operationId": "createEntity",
        "tags": [
          "entities"
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/entity"
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

This is how the schema models in the oneOf is structured.

models/person.json

```
{
    "$id": "person.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "person",
    "required": [ "person" ],
    "description": "A Person",
    "properties": {
        "person": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [ "name" ],
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "$ref": "./name.json",
                    "description": "Full name"
                },
                "ssn": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "Social security number",
                    "example": "19710403-1123"
                },
                "address": {
                    "$ref": "./address.json"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share those subschemas you're referencing please?

Comment: Also, what tooling are you using to generate the docs? (there are many)

Comment: Updated the code with example of a subschema (they all have the same structure).
using: https://github.com/Redocly/redoc

Comment: Schema wise, looks fine. Likely a bug in the library. Suggest you file an issue on their issue tracker.

Comment: @csk87 I'm Redoc author. You schema looks fine. Most likely it's an issue in the lib.
Just file an issue with all the details and ideally minimal reproducible OpenAPI Definition.

Comment: Have you tried using openapi 3.0 instead of 2.0?